# Conditional menu item coloring

Tags: html, css

I am trying to optimize my code.

I have a menu that navigates me between multiple pages. I want to keep the same menu on each page, but I want the name of the page I am currently on to show up in a menu in a different color.

Here is the code I put in each page:

```
<nav class="stroke" data-navigation-handle=".nav_handle" data-navigation-content=".nav_content">
 <ul>
    <li><a href="/MyProjects/index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/MyProjects/Data_Upload.php">Data Upload</a></li>
    <li><a href="/MyProjects/Data Transform.php">Data Transformation</a></li>
    <li><a href="/MyProjects/Process_Flow.php" style="color: orange;">Database View</a></li>
    <li><a href="/MyProjects/Maintenance.php">Maintenance</a></li>
    <li><a href="/MyProjects/Log.php">Log</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

As you can see, I am currently on Database View page, so "Database View" menu item is highlighted in orange. If Log page document, I have "Log" menu item highlighted in Orange.

This solution is simple and it works, but I was wondering if it's possible to do this in a more efficient manner. Something CSS related. I would like to avoid making it it too convoluted, like putting a bunch of if/else statements and echoing lines from PHP, or doing innerHTML from Javascript.

Thanks,
Jake

Comment: Use `:active` in CSS like described [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp)

Comment: Wow. That was simple. Thank you. It helped. Unfortunately, I did some other formatting on the menu items (copied someone else's code) that changes their color when I hover over them. The moment I let go it goes back to its original color. I need to read up on CSS formatting. It's good to know, though, that there is a simple solution.